# Which OpenSSL version supports SHA256?

Tags: php, openssl

I have written a PHP library that uses the `openssl_verify()` and `openssl_sign()`, using SHA256. I think the SHA256 support is kind of new for PHP and OpenSSL, but I don't know which version started to support SHA256.

This causes some problems with the clients using earlier versions of OpenSSL and PHP and I couldn't find the version I specified above.

Which OpenSSL version first supported SHA256 in RSA signing and verifying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to [PHP DOCS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.signature-algos.php) `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` constant vas first added in PHP 5.4.8.

I've also faced this problem while trying to verify SHA256. Don't know what to do now )